# How to generate random numbers of unique modulus values in python

Tags: python, random, modulus

```
import random
value = 1000
a = []
i = 0
b = [None] * 16
print('value = ',1000)
for x in range(value):
    a.append(x)
    random.Random(4).shuffle(a)
print(a)
for x in range(16):
    b[x] = a[x]
print(b)
```

This code generate 16 random numbers selected up to the range 1000.But how to generate numbers that has different modulus values from 1 to 26 like this in python ?

Consider the numerical example

the values obtained randomly are:
`184,15,106,8,93,150,210,144,271,365,65,60,385,164,349,405`
when we perform a `mod 26` operation with all these numbers we get
`0,15,2,8,15,20,2,14,11,1,13,8,21,8,11,15` respectively

here the numbers `15,8,11,2` are repeating. so i want to eliminate this repeatation. for that i want to generate random numbers that have distinct  values while performing a `mod 26` operation.

Comment: What's "unique modulus values"?

Comment: unique modulus numbers means the modulus values( for example 421 mod 26 ) calculated for each randomly selected numbers should be different  or select 16 random numbers those having different modulus values from 1 to 26 as mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you want to find `16` numbers in whose modulo `5` is `4`, with maximum value not greater than `1000`.

**Numpy Solution**

```
def choose_random(max_limit=1000, modulo=5, value=4, size=16):
    x_max = (max_limit - value) // modulo
    if (max_limit - value) % modulo != 0:
        x_max += 1
    x = np.arange(x_max)
    y = x * modulo + value
    return np.random.choice(y, size=size, replace=True)

print(choose_random())
Out: [309 939 449 219 639 614 779 549 189   4 729 629 939 159 934 654]
```

**Simpler Numpy Solution**

```
def choose_random(max_limit=1000, modulo=5, value=4, size=16):
    y = np.arange(value, max_limit, value)
    return np.random.choice(y, size=size, replace=True)
```

If you want `n` different modulo `modulo` values

```
def distinct_modulo(n, modulo):
    if n > modulo:
        raise Exception("Can't return more than {0} distinct values!".format(modulo))
    return np.random.choice(modulo, size=n, replace=False)
```

You simply return `n` distinct values in range `[0, modulo - 1]`

```
distinct_modulo(n=16, modulo=26)
Out: [ 0, 19, 23,  5,  6, 25, 21, 22, 10, 16, 12, 14, 20, 15,  1,  8]
```

**Non Numpy Solution**

```
import random
def distinct_modulo(n, modulo):
    if n > modulo:
        raise Exception("Can't return more than {0} distinct values!".format(modulo))
    return random.sample(range(modulo), n)

distinct_modulo(n=16, modulo=26)     
Out: [14, 17, 13, 10, 1, 6, 0, 20, 2, 21, 4, 19, 9, 24, 25, 16]
```

Comment: The calculated modules values of the selected numbers should be different or each modules value should be unique from another and the modules values can be from the range 1 to 26

Comment: It would be better if you could give us a numerical example above

Comment: I added a simple numerical explanation in the question. hope u understood my question.

Comment: Here also  numbers are repeating in your output. could you please do this without using numpy.

Comment: The error in the last code was `replace=True` must be `replace=False`. Also added non-numpy solution

Answer (score 0):

you can do
import random
random.sample(range(10000), 1000)
this will generate 1000 random numbers

for example to get 10 random number within range 10,000

> > > random.sample(range(10000), 10)
> > >       [3339, 2845, 9485, 2601, 3569, 1332, 7123, 4861, 9893, 9483]